# I have API call pending in one component when i route to another component previous API call has to be cancelled

Tags: angular, api, destroy

I have a problem like i am invoking a API in one component Assume it is in pending state, Now i am routing to another page, The previous API call which was made in the previous route needs to be cancelled

I tried using HttpCancelInterceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpCancelInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private httpCancelService: HttpCancelService) { }

  intercept<T>(req: HttpRequest<T>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
    return next.handle(req).takeUntil(this.httpCancelService.onCancelPendingRequests())
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpCancelService {
  private cancelPendingRequests$ = new Subject<void>()

  constructor() { }

  public cancelPendingRequests() {
    this.cancelPendingRequests$.next()
  }

  public onCancelPendingRequests() {
    return this.cancelPendingRequests$.asObservable()
  }

}
```

In app.component.ts

to make it work it for all the route i wrote like this

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof ActivationEnd) {
    this.httpCancelService.cancelPendingRequests()
  }
})
```

I can't take screenshot of the API
I am explaining with the example

The Result which came when i followed the above code

Page 1 : Invokes 3 API all are in pending state (Count,Amount,Announcement)
when i routed to another page only 1 API got cancelled

Page 2 : Count API        - cancelled
         Amount API       - Pending
         Announcement API - Pending

---

Expected Result:

Page 1 : Count,Amount, Announcement API - In Pending State
Page 2 : Count, Amount, Announcement API - Cancelled State

All the cancel needs to be handled in app.component.ts as generic route change

Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be unsubscribing to the subscriptions made in first component.

Add a `private ngUnsubscribe = new Subject();` field to all components that have `.subscribe()` calls to `Observables` within their class code.

then call `this.ngUnsubscribe.next();` `this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();` in  `ngOnDestroy()` methods.

Example:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
// RxJs 6.x+ import paths
import { filter, startWith, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Myservice} from '../my.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'test-component',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html'
})
export class TestComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
    private ngUnsubscribe = new Subject();

    constructor(private myService: Myservice) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myService.getData()
            .pipe(
               startWith([]),
               filter(data=> data.length > 0),
               takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
            )
            .subscribe(data=> console.log(data));

        this.myService.getAnotherData()
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
            .subscribe(anotherData=> console.log(anotherData));
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
        this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
    }
}
```

It's important to add the `takeUntil` operator as the last one to prevent leaks with intermediate observables in the operator chain.

Comment: Is there any way we can implement this using http interceptor so that we don't have to implement unsubscribe subject in each and every component?